# How to override resource-ref in WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

In my `application.xml`, I have the following:

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>java:app/ds</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

On WebSphere, it allows me to override it to match whatever is available in the container during deployment.  However, in WildFly which requires the data to be resolved in XML files I can't find the capability in `jboss-app.xml` which has nothing defined in http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd to allow for changing resource-refs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not explicitly documented in [JBoss Deployment Descriptors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1) but I found a sample and it actually worked.

For `application.xml` the `lookup-name` needs to be added.

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>java:app/ds</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<lookup-name>java:app/ds</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

`META-INF/jboss-app.xml` in the EAR would then look like (note the namespaces and schemas):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:jboss-app 
  xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" 
  version="7">
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:app/ds</res-ref-name>
    <lookup-name>java:/PacDB</lookup-name>
  </resource-ref>
</jboss:jboss-app>
```

Unfortunately WildFly has more fundamental problems with CDI https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8818 preventing me from actually doing a deployment.  However you can see that it does load up properly from this project https://github.com/trajano/jee/tree/for-JBAS-8818

Answer (score 0):

The resource-ref is defined in web.xml for example using the JavaEE Servlet 3 lookup-name to specify the global jndi name:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee";
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd";
         version="3.0">

     ...

    <!-- JDBC DataSources (java:comp/env/jdbc) -->
    <resource-ref>
        <description>The default DS</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name> <!-- this must match the res-ref-name in the jboss-web.xml -->
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <lookup-name>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</lookup-name>
    </resource-ref>
```

Hence, in EAR, you should be doing this in a web app.